Install specific version of VCLibs debug (Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe)
I need specific version of VCLibs DEBUG: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
I checked many forums and instructions like here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/libraries/c-runtime-packages-desktop-bridge
I install this Universal Windows Tools
but it has only ARM64 and wrong version: 14.0.33519.0
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\Appx\Debug\ARM64)
enter image description here
I didn't have option to install "Universal Windows Platform development" in Workloads, some of the forums points this step but probably all of them are out of date.
does somebody know where can I found this version of VCLibs debug:
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
or how can I create it on my own hand?
Regards,
Hanys

You will need the toolset from MSVC 2015 see C++ binary compatibility between Visual Studio versions

@RichardCritten do you have on mind redistributable version:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#latest-microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-version
?
I have already install this "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Reistributable (x64) - 14.40.33810" and I don't see VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.30704.0 on my PC :/

The debug libs are not redistributable.  You will need the development toolset.

ok, I install MSVC 2015 with development toolset. I have VCLibs.140.00.Debug but 14.0.24210.0 (I need 14.0.30704.0)

I had the same issue on my ARM PC, here is how I solved it.

Open the Visual Studio Installer
Click Modify on the version you are using
Go to the Individual Components tab
Search for "Universal"
Check the box for "C++ Universal Windows Platform support for v143 build tools (ARM64/ARM64EC)"
Click Modify to begin installing


I have already install this component (check the image which I attached) :/
I need x64 (no ARM) and different version


Remove old version (whole folder): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs
Install specific version of MVS -> 2022 LTSC 17.2.0
In configuration select: ""C++ Universal Windows Platform.."
in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\Appx\Debug\x64, you should have desired version of Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug

the second option is:

Remove old version (whole folder): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs
Install specific version of MVS -> 2022 LTSC 17.2.0
In configuration don't select any extra packages which you don't need
After finish installation export your configuration
export configuration
Open configuration in text editor and add this package:
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.MSIX.Packaging",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WindowsAppSDK.Cs"
Open MVS Installer again and import configuration
import configuration
Install
in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\Appx\Debug\x64, you should have desired version of Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug

